# Perform action when UITableViewCell is clicked

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, tvos

I am making an tvOS app for the Apple TV but I have some problems with my `UITableView`.
When I click on a `UITableViewCell` nothing happens. I am using `targetForAction` but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}

let allData = ["Los Angeles","New York","San Fransisco"]

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(allData[indexPath.row])"
    cell.targetForAction("buttonClicked:", withSender: self)
    return cell
}

func buttonClicked(sender:AnyObject) {
    print("button clicked!")
}
```

Comment: Do you have a segue from the `UITableCell`:s (or subclass of) of your `UITableView` to next view? Typically you do this via the storyboard, and prepares possible communication with next view by overloading the `prepareForSegue` method in your table view controller source. <-- since you fixed it yourself, never mind this then!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution.
I had to add this function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("selected cell \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtindexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: Typo: It is [`tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `UITableView` Delegate method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me copy and pasting any of these methods did not work because you need to override the method, and if you try to add the override keyword in front of any of the above methods I got the following error:

> Declaration 'tableView(_:didSelectRowAtindexPath:)' has different argument labels from any potential overrides

The solution was to use XCode to add this method yourself from Auto Suggest, so start typing

> override tableView

and then use the drop down to select the method with the *didSelectRowAtindexPath* text in it.

Inserting this method this way works for me and maybe, is what you also need to do.

Good luck

Comment: All of the old answers are from Swift 2. Most APIs changed in Swift 3. Your answer would be more helpful if you also added the code using the current method signature.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that - I am not sure what you mean by the 'current method signature' though, sorry!

Comment: You copied the typo from @ilkayaktas, that's how you get the warning. The current method signature is [tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview). You should explicitly state that signature in your 'select from drop-down'-part instead of writing the wrong *didSelectRowAtindexPath*.